# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

```
class testF:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class_name__ =  "тест"
        self.simple_commands = ["бред_бред?", "точно_точно?", "test_test?"]

    def filter_message(self, event, vk):
        print(self.__class_name__)
        for command in self.simple_commands:
            if command.split("_")[1] == event.text:
                vk.messages.send(chat_id=event.chat_id, message='Прикинб работает')


    def return_name(self):
        return self.__class_name__
```

Comment: Покажите как вызываете этот код

Comment: И добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: globals()[type].filter_message(event, vk)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\PycharmProjects\VkBots\Kran_Bot\By_VkApi\main.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Nikita\PycharmProjects\VkBots\Kran_Bot\By_VkApi\main.py", line 16, in main
    bred = bredF()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Проблема решилась сама собой xD